# how do I enable/disable textinput programmatically in expo?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

the problem is that I am trying enable/disable fields in a form with the use of a

I have tried following the steps in this tutorial

https://dev.to/skptricks/react-native-enable-and-disable-textinput-programmatically-1b99

Here is where I have got to so far

```
onPressButton = () => {  
  this.setState({ TextInputDisableStatus: false })  
}

              <TextInput
                label="Name"
                placeholder="Colin Molony"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                keyboardType="default"
                keyboardAppearance="default"
                returnKeyType="next"
                returnKeyLabel="Next"
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                selectTextOnFocus={true}
                style={styles.textInput}
                editable={this.state.TextInputDisableHolder}
            />

ProfileScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Profile Page',
  headerRight: (
    <Ionicons
        style={{padding: 15}}
        name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-create' : 'md-create'}
        size={26}
        onPress={this.onPressButton}
      />
  ),
};
```

When I click the icon I get the following error this.setstate is not a function

Comment: can you provide the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a naming problem. I followed your link and the author there initializes the following state:

```
constructor() {  
super();  
this.state = { TextInputDisableStatus: true }  
}
```

In the onPress method, you are updating the status with:

```
onPressButton = () => {  
  this.setState({ TextInputDisableStatus: false })  
}
```

But then inside the TextInput the author and you are referring to

```
editable={this.state.TextInputDisableHolder}
```

this should probably be changed to:

```
editable={this.state.TextInputDisableStatus}
```

**In addition** you have to change:

```
onPressButton()  {  
  this.setState({ TextInputDisableStatus: false })  
}
```

and:

```
<Ionicons
    style={{padding: 15}}
    name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-create' : 'md-create'}
    size={26}
    onPress={() => this.onPressButton()}
  />
```